# Error git-receive-pack not permitted en NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, git, github

Estoy intentando subir un proyecto a github pero cada vez que lo intento salta el error de *https://luzsdx@github.com/luzsdx/Ejercicio-static.git: git-receive-pack not permitted on 'https://luzsdx@github.com/luzsdx/Ejercicio-static.git/'* .
Ya intenté reemplazar la contraseña por el token y tengo verificada la cuenta.

Salida del comando:

*==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 05:43:50 Pushing - EjercicioStatic
git branch
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git submodule status
git push https://luzsdx@github.com/luzsdx/Ejercicio-static.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
git push https://luzsdx@github.com/luzsdx/Ejercicio-static.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 05:44:38 Pushing - EjercicioStatic finished.
==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 05:45:08 Pushing - EjercicioStatic
git branch
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git submodule status
git push https://github.com/luzsdx/Ejercicio-static.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 05:45:22 Pushing - EjercicioStatic finished.
==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 05:48:03 Pushing - EjercicioStatic
git branch
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git submodule status
git push https://github.com/luzsdx/Ejercicio-static.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 05:57:45 Pushing - EjercicioStatic finished.
==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 06:03:43 Pushing - EjercicioStatic
git branch
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git submodule status
git push https://github.com/luzsdx/Ejercicio-static.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 06:16:33 Pushing - EjercicioStatic finished.
==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 06:16:58 Pushing - EjercicioStatic
git branch
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git submodule status
git push https://luzsdx@github.com/luzsdx/Ejercicio-static.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 06:22:16 Pushing - EjercicioStatic finished.
==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 06:25:35 Pushing - EjercicioStatic
git branch
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git submodule status
git push https://luzsdx@github.com/luzsdx/Ejercicio-static.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 06:25:57 Pushing - EjercicioStatic finished.
==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 06:34:29 Pushing - EjercicioStatic
git branch
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git submodule status
git push https://luzsdx@github.com/luzsdx/Ejercicio-static.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
==[IDE]== 24/01/2023 06:51:29 Pushing - EjercicioStatic finished.*

Comment: Hola, @luz. Podrías poner el comando con su salida completa en la pregunta? Si no lo sabes formatear, no importa. Nosotros la editamos y entonces podrías ver cómo se hace para la próxima oportunidad.

Comment: hola @eftshift0 la verdad no se formatearlo, como podria hacer lo del comando y el formateo?

Comment: Tal parece que es un problema de permisos. Tienes bien configurado el URL del repositorio? Tienes bien configurado el password? Tu usuario tiene acceso al repositorio?

Comment: Solo copia el texto de la consola (comando y salida) y pégalo en la pregunta más o menos donde te gustaría que se viera. Luego nosotros (alguien, podría ser yo) la formateamos.

Comment: @eftshift0 con decir bien configurado el URL y el password a que te refieres? mi usuario es el creador del respositorio, disculpa las preguntas, soy nueva en esto

Comment: Para interactuar con un remoto (github, en este caso), debes tener bien configurado tu usuario y contraseña (que podría ser un token.... la verdad yo uso SSH para configurar los remotos así que no tengo mucha experiencia con este tema de los usuarios/tokens).

Comment: y en la salida que colocaste, no se ve el error que comentas al principio de la pregunta.

Comment: y como seria SSH para configurarlos? ya que lo que ahora estoy haciendo no me estaria funcionando

Comment: Con ssh uno crea un certificado (que incluso creo que se puede hacer el el proveedor, pero se puede hacer por consola, con ssh-keygen) y se registra la llave _publica_ en el hosting. La llave privada la guardas y no la compartes con nadie. Entonces haces `ssh-add` de la llave privada. Los remotos que ya tengas configurados con https, los cambias para que el URL sea el de ssh (mira en la información de los repositorios en la página del hosting... ahi se puede ver la URL para clonar con ssh.... no tendrías que clonar, solo ajustar el URL en la configuración de los repos.

Comment: Te recomendaría que trates de clonar primero otro repositorio con ssh hasta que lo hagas funcionar y veas los detalles para que no dañes lo que ya tienes hecho.